# Firebase Phone Auth OTP delay

Tags: react-native, firebase-authentication, one-time-password

I am using firebase react native APIs - https://rnfirebase.io/ for a RN app. The users have to login via google into the app ([API ref](https://rnfirebase.io/auth/social-auth#google)) At some point I ask the users to provide their contact numbers for verification. I am using this API (also provided by rnfirebase) - https://rnfirebase.io/auth/phone-auth#main

Specifically I am using the `auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)`  method. This method is called when user submits their phone number and wait for OTP.

Here's where I am facing issues. The OTP takes ~ 15 seconds to arrive and then the method mentioned above takes additional ~ 10 seconds to resolve. Meaning, the user would have to wait for almost 25 sec to be able to see the OTP field.

I have tried googling this issue but haven't found much. I am not sure what more piece of code would be helpful here. The versions of SDKs I am using are -

```
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^17.3.0",
"@react-native-firebase/auth": "^16.1.1",
"@react-native-firebase/database": "^17.3.0",
"@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^16.1.1",
"@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^8.0.1",
```

Note - I am not facing the error of OTPs not being received, OTPs come but with a delay.

I expect the delay in receiving the OTP to be under 5 sec (on average)